# Batch file - how to create a folder with a promt, and then copy a file into that folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a specific issue I'd like help with.

I want to write a batch file that first prompts a user to name a folder, to be created in a designated location. I then want to copy a file from a designated location into that `new folder`.

I have a batch file that does one or the other, but not both.

Is it possible to tell the batch file to copy a file into a new folder it just created?

This is what I wrote so far:

```bat
@echo off

:start
cd "C:\Target Folder"
set /p x= Please Enter Your Folder Name :
md %x%
xcopy /w "D:\" "C:\Target Folder\" /s/e/i
```

Comment: Are you on a version of WIndows that supports **PowerShell**? If so, go with that. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77e51894-c591-469f-b3d3-982ab4f76ca7/if-else-if-condition-in-batch-files?forum=ITCG

Comment: You don't mention the error you get when you run this, but it looks like your xcopy command should copy all of drive D: to the "target folder", and not the new directory inside the target folder.  Shouldn't it be more like xcopy <switches> D:\<filename> "C:\Target Folder\%x%"

Comment: Larryc, thank you for the feedback.  I was able to fix it and get it working based on your assistance.  Thanks!

@echo off
: start
cd "C:\TargetFolder"
set /p x= Please Enter Your Folder Name:
md %x%
xcopy /w/s/e/i C:\SourceFolder C:\TargetFolder\%x%